# how to decrease the size of font / menu bar in a html drop down menu

Tags: html, css, menu

Hi this is probably an easy question. I am trying to make a drop down navigation menu but unfortunately the space where this menu will be is limited and I am having trouble figuring out how to decrease the font size and menu size so that I can add more options and make it fit inside the section. all the searches I have found  about decreasing font size and

size so far does not work. Can someone tell me how to do this?

below is my code

sorry again if this is an simple answer

```css
.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
  width: 190px;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.second-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  /*width: 220px;*/
  background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
  /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
  display: inline;
}
/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a
/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */

{
  font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-level-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Reporting </a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">test1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Process Optimization</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Operations </a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Access </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">exit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <ul class="third-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Anniversary Letters</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">authorizations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Documentation</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tasks</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Compliance</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Connect Site</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: So reducing the font size from 14px to something smaller does not work?

Comment: Have you considered using bootstrap? Is that an option for you? It is responsive and will allow you to dropdown to a hamburger menu on mobile/limited width devices. https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your culprit:

```
.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Instead of using the shorthand version (which, is often preferable however), use:

```
.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
    {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 10px;
    ..etc 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the css: `font-size: value;` ?
eksample: `font-size: 10px;` or `font-size:0.7em;`

```css
.third-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -150px;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.third-level-menu > li {
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
  width: 190px;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.second-level-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: none;
}
.second-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  height: 30px;
  background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.top-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 30px;
  /*width: 220px;*/
  background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover {
  background: #CCCCCC;
}
.top-level-menu li:hover > ul {
  /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
  display: inline;
}
/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a
/* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */

{
  /*CHANGE THE VALUE HERE:*/
  font: bold 0.7em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
  display: block;
  line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover {
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="top-level-menu">
  <li><a href="#">Reporting </a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">test1</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test2</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test3</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">test4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>


  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Process Optimization</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Operations </a>
    <ul class="second-level-menu">
      <li><a href="#">Access </a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">exit</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Support</a>
        <ul class="third-level-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Anniversary Letters</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">authorizations</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Documentation</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Tasks</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Compliance</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Connect Site</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```